# How to transition with URL query param in ember routing?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

when my page loads, I am just typing the following:

```
credit-card/credit-cardno?country=SG
```

now I am getting country as "SG". fine. But how can I make transition to next page with above details?

I tried like this:

```
this.transitionTo('HK.cs2i.cs2i.purchase.purchaseReview?country=SG');
```

But getting error. do i require to update my `routerjs` or my transitionTo is wrong?

once the page transition done, I would like to see my URL as :

`HK/cs2i/cs2i/purchase/purchaseReview?country=SG`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get? And did you define the queryParam in the route `HK/cs2i/cs2i/purchase/purchaseReview`? Also see [Query Parameters](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/routing/query-params/).

Comment: I am not getting error. But my transition not works. can you please show me a correct way?

Comment: @Enno - the document not pretty clear at all.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
this.transitionTo('HK.cs2i.cs2i.purchase.purchaseReview',{queryParams:{country:SG}});
```

Also you can try this:

```
this.transitionTo('/HK/cs2i/cs2i/purchase/purchaseReview?country=SG');
```

Source from [Ember API](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Route/methods/transitionTo?anchor=transitionTo)

Comment: will try. do I require to change / update anything in router.js file too..? can you please help me here?

Comment: use dots in your `router.js`. you don't need to update your `router.js`